# Python arrays for solving equations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am writing a simple solver for the heat equation to get used to the python programming language. The code I have is the following:

```
for i in range(1,m):
    c=gamma*p*(q[i-1]+q[i])
    rhs=np.matmul(B,np.transpose(u[i-1,:]))+np.transpose(c)
    sol=np.linalg.solve(A,rhs[0])
    u[i,:]=np.transpose(sol)
print('Simulation Complete!')
```

The problem I have is with understanding the matrix structure. The usual programming language I use, Matlab, there is a very strict way you deal with arrays, just like maths, you have to be careful with your dimensions. It seems that this isn't the case with python. In the final few lines of my code, I've been treating both row and column vectors as different, but this has been too cumbersome, is there a way I can make these things more efficient?

At the moment I seem to be treating everything as an array and to properly get a vector from the linear algebra solver, I have to choose the first element. Can I be a bit looser with my inputs, or can I get more rigorous with how I define my matrices, so keep tabs on if they're row of column vectors?

Answer (score 0):

in numpy you can define column vectors, row vectors and 2D matrices.

eg:

```
>>> np.ones((1,4))
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.]])

>>> np.ones((4,1))
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])

>>> np.ones((4,4))
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

You can do:

```
>>> np.dot(2*np.ones((1,4)), np.ones((4,4)))
array([[8., 8., 8., 8.]])
```

You can also do

```
>>> np.dot(np.ones((4,4)), 2*np.ones((4,1)))
array([[8.],
       [8.],
       [8.],
       [8.]])
```

But if you try to do

```
>>> np.dot(np.ones((4,4)), 2*np.ones((1,4)))

or 

>>> np.dot(2*np.ones((4,1)), np.ones((4,4)))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot
ValueError: shapes (4,1) and (4,4) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)
```

So as you can see, dimensions are taken in account, and some operations are not allowed if the dimensions of the vectors involved don't match